# Attempt and retry

Tags: c#

How can I formalize this to be more generic, where I can specify an X exceptions to throw and X exceptions to try again all while improving the code readability.

```
private const int RetrySegmentCount = 3;
private const int SecondsBetweenRetry = 30;
var retryCounter = 0;

while (true)
{
    try
    {
        ExecuteProcessThatMayThrow();
        break;
    }
    catch (NotSupportedException) // Do no retry if this is thrown
    {
        throw;
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        if (retryCounter < RetrySegmentCount)
        {
            retryCounter++;
            Thread.Sleep(SecondsBetweenRetry * 1000);
        }
        else
        {
            throw;
        }
    }
}
```

An ideal syntax in puesdocode might be

`Repeat(3, 30, [NotSupportedException], [Exception]) => ExecuteProcessThatMayThrow();`

`Repeat(3, 30) => ExecuteProcessThatMayThrow();` // This will repeat on all

`Repeat(3, 30, [NotSupportedException, VeryBadException], [RetryableException]) => ExecuteProcessThatMayThrow();`

Comment: Check out Polly

Comment: "where I can specify an X exceptions to throw and X exceptions to try again all while improving the code readability" By **not** throwing exceptions to handle a usual program-flow.

Comment: https://github.com/App-vNext/Polly

Comment: Polly looks exactly what Id like but its a bit much, unless I can find a usecase for everything it offers I prefer just a simple method  I can reuse in a 3-4 places. There is overhead in maintaining a nuget package (albeit small)

Comment: *"Insanity is doing the same thing over and over and expecting different results"* What changes between calls? Maybe you can verify that the operation will succeed before you try to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a reusable method that has multiple result depending on the error type. Here a small modified version of what i use

This method handles the different conditions and retry

```
public static bool TryExecute(Action action, int retry, int secondBeforeRetry, List<Type> notSupportedExceptions, List<Type> veryBadExceptions, List<Type> retryableExceptions)
    {
        var success = false;

        // keep trying to run the action
        for (int i = 0; i < retry; i++)
        {
            try
            {
                // run action
                action.Invoke();

                // if it reached here it was successful
                success = true;

                // break the loop
                break;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                // if the exception is not retryable
                if (!retryableExceptions.Contains(ex.GetType()))
                {
                    // if its a not supported exception
                    if (notSupportedExceptions.Contains(ex.GetType()))
                    {
                        throw new Exception("No supported");
                    }
                    else if (veryBadExceptions.Contains(ex.GetType()))
                    {
                        throw new Exception("Very bad");
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(secondBeforeRetry * 1000);
                }
            }
        }

        return success;
    }
```

To call this method it before very easy as they can all be easily change to optional parameters. here is and example :

```
    // sample action that force an error to be thrown
    var a = new Action(() =>
    {
        var test = "";
        var test2 = test[3]; // throw out of range exception
    });

    try
    {
        var success = TryExecute(a, 5, 30, new List<Type>() { typeof(IndexOutOfRangeException) }, new List<Type>(), new List<Type>());
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        // handle whatever you want
    }
```